# how to override JSONAPI.configure from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have gem "my_gem" that contains this initializer placed in `config/initializers/jsonapi-resources_initializer.rb`

content

```
require 'jsonapi-resources'
require 'jsonapi/exceptions/access_denied'
require 'jsonapi/exceptions/unauthorized'

JSONAPI.configure do |config|
  config.maximum_page_size = 100
end
```

then I have classic rails app that use this "my_gem" gem

in app I have another initializer `config/initializers/jsonapi_resources.rb`
content

```
JSONAPI.configure do |config|
  config.maximum_page_size = 1_000
end
```

At the moment the rails app overrides `maximum_page_size` it is `1_000`, but I want to use this config

```
config.maximum_page_size = 100
```

instead of original config.maximum_page_size = 1_000

but I can't change original app, so how change this config from the gem side?

tried to use after initializer but it is not good idea